# HTML Entity decoding to Special characters

Tags: html, sql, oracle

I want to display special symbols in my output.
For eg: My text may contain entity codes like `&lt;`, `&gt`; etc.
I want to display this as `<`, `>` in my output. I need to do this in SQL.
I googled about this and got a function,

`select dbms_xmlgen.convert('ABC <; ',0) from dual`

This does the reverse process, it generates the output as 'ABC <'

I tried with decoding but it does not work. I even changed the sql command as,
`select dbms_xmlgen.convert('ABC <; ',1) from dual`, where 1 is for `entity_decode`, but I don't get the desired output.

Comment: What output do you get, and what's wrong with it? Using `0` for encode and `1` for decode seems to work fine for me, in 11gR2, in place of the ENTITY_ENCODE and ENTITY_DECODE constants which don't seem to be usable outside PL/SQL. (I assume you're actually calling it as `convert('ABC &lt; ',1)`, not what you've shown...)

Comment: select dbms_xmlgen.convert('ABC &lt;; ',1) from dual, this is the sql that am running.

Comment: That gives me `ABC <;`, so is that not what you want/expect, or are you getting something different? (Hopefully it's not just prompting you for a value for `lt`... if so that really should have been mentioned by now...)

Comment: I need ABC < only , thats my requirement, but Why that does not work for me

Comment: Huh? Because you have two semicolons in your initial string? `select dbms_xmlgen.convert('ABC &lt;',1) from dual` will give you that output. The string you converted from had `ABC <;` so why wouldn't you have expected converting back to give you exactly the same?

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using DBMS_XMLGEN.convert, I used the function UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE:

```
SELECT UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE('ABC &lt; ') FROM DUAL;
```

result:

```
ABC <
```

More information on the Oracle doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_i18n.htm#i998992

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT('ABC &lt; ', DBMS_XMLGEN.ENTITY_DECODE) FROM DUAL
```

Also, see the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100) for that.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so apparently this is a bug in some Oracle versions (9.2.0.1 and 10.1.0.2, as it seems). [Somebody solved it](http://www.44342.com/ORACLE-f253-t7468-p1.htm) by wrapping the function. I don't know how that's supposed to solve it, but it my be worth trying. Create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
   xml_decode(
      i_xml_string IN VARCHAR2
   )
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
   RETURN
      DBMS_XMLGEN.convert(
         i_xml_string,
         DBMS_XMLGEN.ENTITY_DECODE
      );
END;
```

And use it instead:

```
SELECT xml_decode('ABC &lt; ') FROM DUAL;
```

Let us know if that works.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this one, but it shows error as "ENTITY DECODE" is invalid identifier

Comment: Even with the `DBMS_XMLGEN.` prefix? I just added that.

Comment: With DBMS_XMLGEN , it shows that ENTITY DECODE is not a procedure or it is undefined

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible workaround, see if that helps.

Comment: It appears that constants declared in PL/SQL packages are not visible to plain SQL, only to other PL/SQL code; not sure I knew that. (`select dbms_types.success from dual` also fails, for example). So I don't think this is a bug, exactly. Wrapping it in any PL/SQL block works. But using the constant values, `0` or `1`, might be a simpler workaround for plain SQL use, at the risk of the constants changing one day.

Comment: @user2552670 - 'does not work' is not an error message or at all useful. If you want help you have to explain what's actually happening.

Comment: @AlexPoole is 100% correct. In order to use a "constant" in Oracle (not sure of others) SQL it has to be declared as a function, so for example `cMyConstant varchar2(1) := 'A';` cannot be used but `function cMyConstant return varchar2 begin return 'A'; end;` can. So really, Oracle woudl have been more sensible to declare ENTITY_DECODE as a package function "constant" in my opinion.

Comment: Also this is a slight "aside" but I thought it may be useful to mention here that if you want to decode numeric XML entities such as &#160; then utl_i18n.unescape_reference will work (dbms_xmlgen.convert ignores them)